# Schema.ini - determine file types

Tags: vba, ms-access, text, schema, driver

According to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353(v=vs.85).aspx),I can use JET to determine data type.

How can I use this feature and also explicitly declare certain columns.  For example, my schema looks like the below:

```
[GCSBD02.txt]
ColNameHeader=True
MaxScanRows=0
CharacterSet=OEM
Format=CSVDelimited
Col1="Campaign" Text
Col2="Site (DCM)" Text
Col3="Date" DateTime
Col4="Month" Text
Col6="Creative" Text
Col7="Placement Rate" Long
```

Notice that there is no `Col5`.  I want Jet to determine the type for `Col5`.  As it is when I read the text file into a program, it stops reading data at Col4.  I assume this is due the ODBC Text File Driver.  Does anyone know how to properly format this?

Thanks,

FYI - i'm doing this as part of the import process for sending data to ms-access

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question?  What does your data look like? Are you trying to get JET to guess the type soem columns and not others.  Are you expeciting it to guess the type on a row by row basis?

Comment: 1. My data could be anything.  This is part of a generic importing algorithm I'm building.  Essentially the user will specify the type for most columns, but I need JET to take a swing at anything they don't.  2. Yes to the second question.  I need Jet to determine the type for any column I don't specify.  3. No, it doesn't need to be row by row (I think this would be the wrong tool for that, not to mention its sort of a crazy idea).